# Apical meristem regrowth?

Tags: botany

When the shoot apical meristem is cut out/removed, it induces lateral growth. I'm wondering if this means that that stem will never grow vertically again. Is there a way to stop lateral growth after the apical meristem is removed? Is there a way to grow that meristem back again?

Thank you

Comment: If you again cut all the apical buds of lateral branches, the same would induced on the lateral branches.

Comment: Keeping the plant alive, one way to maintain the "apical-dominance" of a certain branch, could be adding auxin (a group of plant hormone) artificially.  (the same function was served by shoot apex). But since you rejected the apical-meristem, the axis will no-more grow tall. However, an way could be there; grafting an apex on the cutaway top.

Comment: what plant? Different plants will give you very different answers here